# Syntax Error: Unexpected Identifier in for-loop in AngularJS $http.get

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Why am I getting a 'syntax error: unexpected identifier' and why does my browser gets stuck in a continuous loop after I run this code? I'm using setInterval to delay the requests to the API per the API request guidelines.

```
var tempArray = []; 
var arr = [];   
//angular controller    
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    setInterval($http.get(url).success(function(data) {
        tempArray.push(data);
        arr.push(tempArray);
    }), 1000);
}
```

Comment: _Where_ are you getting "unexpected identifier"? Also, if you want to _delay_ a request, you probably want `setTimeout` - using `setInterval` will _continually_ call the supplied function every 1 second.

Comment: AngularJS apps should use the `$timeout` service for delays because it properly integrates `window.setTimeout` with the AngularJS framework. For more information, see [AngularJS $timeout Service API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout);

Comment: Either way, both `$timeout` and `window.setTimeout` require the first argument be a function. The $http service returns a promise object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @vlaz has explained, you want `setTimeout` if you want to "delay" something. `setInterval` will continually call the supplied callback.

I'm a little confused why the API guidelines say to "delay" requests though... do they mean "debounce"?

Either way... the "unexpected identifier" syntax error will be because you are not passing a function as the first argument to `setInterval`. You need:

```
setTimeout(function() {
  $http.get(url).success(function(data) {
    tempArray.push(data);
    arr.push(tempArray);
  });
}, 1000);
```

`$http.get(url).success()` does not return a function that `setTimeout` can call so you cannot pass it directly.

Comment: Thank you @jjenzz!

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the `$http` to your Controller. Like:

```
myApp.controller('MainController', function MainController($scope,$http) {...}
```

And with the usage of `setInterval`the code repeats again and again. In your case every second.